# Где Kubernete Postgresql хранит данные

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Я прочитал много форумов, но так и не нашел об этом вообще ничего. Как я знаю, что если docker контейнер упадет, то все данные из базы удалятся и для этого вписывают volume для хранения данных. Но я не смог найти это в kubenetes.

Я бы хотел узнать нужно ли это делать, если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основной ресурс (API-объект) в Kubernetes для приложений, которые хранят/используют постоянные данные (т.е. stateful), — это [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/). *(Они похожи на ReplicaSets, предназначенные для stateless-приложений.)* В StatefulSets определяются PersistentVolumeClaims (PVC), которые и ссылаются на PersistentVolumes (подробнее о них было в [соседнем комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222447/420436)).

Вообще же, для более простого управления СУБД вроде PostgreSQL в Kubernetes можно использовать готовые [Kubernetes-операторы](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/), где решены эти (и многие другие) проблемы эксплуатации. Такие операторы создают нужные StatefulSets, а также могут позволять хранить данные на внешних облачных хранилищах — например, [оператор от Zalando](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator) полноценно поддерживает [AWS EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/).

*P.S. Русскоязычный обзор с актуальным списком операторов конкретно для PgSQL (Stolon, Crunchy Data, Zalando, KubeDB, StackGres) и сравнением их возможностей [есть здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/flant/blog/527524/).*

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, если хранить данные в файловой системе контейнера, то сохранность их не гарантируется. kubernetes может в любой момент остановить (уничтожить) контейнер, чтобы, например, перенести его на другой узел для распределения нагрузки. В этом случае все данные в файловой системе такого контейнера будут утеряны.

Правильный подход, это использовать [persisten volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/), которые в свою очередь основаны на `volume` из `docker`. Это долговременное хранилище, по сути как отдельный диск, который может быть присоединен к контейнеру, но не привязан к его жизненному циклу. Т.е. даже при остановках и пересозданиях конейнера/пода он будет хранить данные.